# gradle multimodule project with 'base' plugin build dependency

Tags: gradle, multi-module

Multimodule project having java, css, script, etc submodules. I'd like to make it "the right way", but having trouble to understand why gradle does not keep the build order based on specified dependencies.

```
// web-client submodule, which depends on other two submodules
apply plugin: 'base'

dependencies {
    project(':web-scripts')
    project(':web-styles')
}
```

And then 'web-scripts' submodules I have defined like that:

```
// web-scripts submodule
apply plugin: 'base'
...
// I also tried to define an artifact, but did not figure out the effect of it
artifacts {
    archives file("$buildDir/web-scripts.zip")
}
```

So, when I run 'gradle clean build' in the the 'web-client' folder, it does not force the web-scripts module build at all. What do I do wrong? I also tried to bind these to a named configuration.